# Flutter App Cant Authenticate to Google Drive API Using google_sign_in Package

Tags: android, flutter, google-drive-api, google-signin

My Flutter app (Android variant) is unable to authenticate to **Google Drive** API using the **google_sign_in** package (ver 5.4.2) along with the **extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth** package (vers 2.0.7).

The exact error that I am getting is:

```
PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException:10:,null, null’)’
```

I am NOT using Firebase, so all of the Google API config items is done via **Google Cloud Console** instead of Firebase Console as is usually the case with previous post having the same error as I have.

My box is Mac Air M1, and since my Flutter app is an Android variant and that there is still no Android emulator for the M1, my debugging is done via a real Android device tethered to the computer via a USB C cable.

Code snippet is as follows:

```
Future<http.Client> getHttpClientFromGoogle() async {
    
   String clientIdOAuth = <from client id string in Google Cloud Console (see below)>;                     

   List scopes = [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file' ];

   GoogleSignIn signIn = GoogleSignIn(clientId: clientIdOAuth,scopes:scopes);

    signIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen(
      (user) {
        print(user);
      },
    );

    var _account = await signIn.signIn();    <— Exception happens here.

    <more code here>
}
```

The problem occurs when I attempt to sign in, causing the consent form to come up. Exception is thrown after I select the email of the designated tester.

ie-
[image]

flutter doctor output is as follows:

[image]

This is what I've done in **Google Cloud Console**:

- I created a Google Cloud project
- Under the **APIs & Services** > **Enabled APIs & Service** page, I enabled **Google Drive API** and **People API**.
- Under the **APIs & Services** > **Credentials** page, I hit **Create Credentials**, to create an **OAuth Client ID** by registering an app with the following characteristics:

- Application Type: Android
- Package Name: <— set to value of the **package** attribute in the **manifest** tag in <project_root>/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
- SHA1 certificate fingerprint: <— set to the SHA1 specified in the app signing report generated by running ./gradlew signingReport in the Android Studio terminal. NOTE: I also verified that this SHA1 is in my **debug.keystore** file.
- Under **APIs & Services** > **OAuth Consent Screen** page, I verified the following:
- My publishing status: Testing
- User Type: External
- I then hit **Edit App**.
- In the resulting page, I hit **Save and Continue** to get to the **Scopes** page where I specify the scope that I need when using the Google Drive API.
- I hit **Save and Continue** again to get to the page where I specify the email of the users that shall be allowed to the test the app.
- Test Users: <— Set to the email of the users allowed to test the app.

I apologize for the long post. Its just that I've been at this for a while, trying all of the suggestions from previous posts, all to no avail. Also, I used to have no problems authenticating with Google API using the **googleapis_auth** package. Its just that when Google disabled **loopback flow** which **googleapis_auth** relied upon, it was recommended I switched to **google_sign_in**

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

/Jose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useing package [google_sign_in: ^5.4.2](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in)

```
  Future<void> gmailSignIn(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
      if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
        final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
        await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
        print("idToken = ${googleSignInAuthentication.idToken}");
        final AuthCredential authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken, accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken);
        print("accessToken = ${authCredential.accessToken}");
        // Getting users credential
        UserCredential result = await auth.signInWithCredential(authCredential);
        User? user = result.user;
        print("user details = ${user.toString()}");

   
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print("Error on google sign in");
      print(e.message);
      rethrow;
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error hai");
      print(e);
      rethrow;
    } finally {
     
    }    
  }
```

Comment: thank you for your response. And Im confirming that by not passing the clientId and scopes named arguments to the GoogleSignIn() object instantiation will get rid of the PlatformException() error I was getting.

Question though: How will I pass these arguments to GoogleSignIn? If my app was using Firebase, Id assume they'd be in the google-services.json file. But since its not, I have no clue.